# Unable to click link with Selenium in Python

Tags: selenium

I am working on a web scraping project at the moment. The website I am trying to get data from is not the easiest to work with.  I am using Selenium, and have worked my way through most of the items I want to select.

The website: http://crashinformationky.org/AdvancedSearch

I can get the website to open, and select different properties.  But when I select Data, then try and "click" on Today, to change the date.  Nothing works.

I have tried using the xpath, css selectore, link text, partial link text, nothing works.

Here is my most recent attempt.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5).until(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#QueryPanel-cond-2 > div:nth-child(4) > a'))
date_one = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#QueryPanel-cond-2 > div:nth-child(4) > a')
date_one.click()
date_one_enter = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dp1647307835636"]')
date_one_enter.send_keys('01/01/2016')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Kyle!

As a personal preference I like to use Full XPATH's when selecting items with Selenium. I was able to click on TODAY, clear the field, send a new date and hit ENTER. See below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
url = "http://crashinformationky.org/AdvancedSearch"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/a"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[10]/div/div[3]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/a"))).click()
field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/input")
field.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "a")
field.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
field.send_keys('01/01/2016')
field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Do note that I am using a MAC, so when I send the `Keys.COMMAND` that would be `Keys.CONTROL` for Windows.

Comment: Thank you for this.  
So for some reason whenever I use your code, it works great until it gets to the command to click on the today field.  It says:

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Everything else up until then is working great.

Comment: @KyleHamsley Are you using Chrome? What version of Selenium? I am not seeing this problem with my code.

Comment: Yes chrome Version 99.0.4844.51

Selenium is 4.1.2

Comment: So I added time.sleep(1) to some of the lines, and it started working fine.

Thank you for the help?

Comment: @Kyle Hamsley perfect! Could you mark my answer correct?